# Can I get alignment value for class using DIA SDK?

Tags: c#, dia-sdk

I am making app in c# that can list all classes/structs with their members like from pdb using DIA SDK but I don't know how to get alignment value. I tried to search it in microsoft docs https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/tree/master/docs/debugger/debug-interface-access but I wasn't able to find any property that returns class/struct alignment.
Can I get it somehow using DIA SDK or I need to manually calculate it using offsets of members?

Comment: I haven't used this API in ages, but don't you get the field offsets from it?

Comment: Yes but I want alignment value so I can use alignas keyword